# Twig Empty Variable -> Exception?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am running through a loop in Twig:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div class="description">
   Title: {{ item.name }}<br />
   Price: {{ item.price }}
</div>
{% else %}
<p>...</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If item.price is empty, it throws me an exception. Can't I just simply force Twig to give out "nothing" when a certain value is empty?

Or do I always need to {% if item.x %}{{ item.x }}{% endif %} for all values?

Answer (score 13):

You could also try the [`default` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html):

```
{{ item.price|default("nothing") }}
```

Answer (score 12):

Go to config.yml and set the following there:

```
twig:
    strict_variables: false
```

Answer (score 5):

```
{% if item.price is defined and item.price not in [''] %}
    {{ item.price }}
{% endif %}
```

Should do the trick, or that is at least how I have handled it in the past. I am not a Twig expert though :)

Comment: A bit nicer replacement is `{% if item.price is defined and item.price not empty %}`, though my vote goes to `@Problematic` answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is my shortest version for this situation:

```
{{ item.price|default }}
```

`default`-filter's default is `FALSE`, so it will output nothing and not raise an exception.